# Symfony Form filtered drop down choice

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I have for with drop down entity Customer by field name, my question how to change form for filter by name. Example in my drop down many customer, and I write "a" and in drop down remained only who have first letter in name "a"

```
        $builder
        ->add('customer', 'entity', array(
            'class' => Customer::class,
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control select2 all_customers'),
            'property' => 'name',
            'empty_value' => 'Choice Customer',
            'query_builder' => function ($repository) {
                /** @var CustomerRepository  $repository */
                return $repository->getAllQuery();
            },
            'required' => false
        ))
```

this my template what need to do which create text field for filter

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_errors(form) }}

{{ form_label(form.customer, label|default(null), {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
{{ form_widget(form.customer, {'attr': {'class': 'select2', 'type': 'text'}}) }}

 {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: It is a JS issue and unrelated with Symfony. If you have a full list of options on client side, you can use any jQuery (as specified in the tags of question) plugin to implement a filterable select box.

Comment: I dont know jquery, what I need to add to field in template ?

Comment: Nothing to add to PHP or Twig, they are not provide this functionality. Because it is a _frontend_ issue and there are billions ways to solve it (through jQuery or "vanilla" JS), try to search "autocomplete select".